# What is a general word for a shape which allows entry/exit through only one of its faces?

Tags: single-word-requests, shapes

What is a general word for a shape which has only one entry/exit side or face?

For example, if it's a rectangle with 4 sides, then things can only pass in/out from one its side while other sides are blocked.

The field of context is mathematics, computation, physics.

Comment: Hello @user84428. Please take a look at the [tag help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for this sort of question, particularly the checklist at the end. A good sentence with a blank for your word is needed, along with other information.

Comment: You might get good answers at https://math.stackexchange.com with the `[euclidean-geometry]` tag.

Comment: I'd call it a _Container_. That's what the metaphor is. Since it's mathematics, it can be  defined without reference to number of dimensions, but it's gonna have an area and a circumference, (or a volume and a surface), and apparently an opening, and their existence is invariant.

Comment: What kinds of "things" could possibly be entering a two-dimensional shape like a 4-sided rectangle?

Comment: They're not going to all be the same shape, though, so there won't be a single word since they're not a single shape. You could, for example, say something's U-shaped to denote only one side's open, but only if it's actually U-shaped and isn't, for example, decagon, or some other polygon missing a side. Also, if it's a land shape, "peninsula" denotes a shape with only one open side for entry and egress, or if it's a water shape, words like bay, gulf, cove, etc. denote such a shape. And these are all just two-dimensional shape examples, not even addressing the many three-dimensional ones.

Comment: I doubt such a word exists. The problem as stated may apply to any number of dimensions, so even if we have a word based on normal experience, such as bin (which may do in some circumstance), it is unlikely to apply in general. Words such as portal or sieve are relevant but apply to the access rather than the container. I am stuck.

Comment: It occurs to me that the general term for a surface with an aperture is **a bottle**. However, I do not offer this as an answer because the less forgiving or less topologically inclined readers will say that a bottle does not have faces, as specified by the question.

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer, because you specify a particular field (mathematics) and then you want a general word; you are in a sense asking people outside the field to propose terms which may be rejected by people inside the field for reasons unknown to us. You need to ask this over on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I suppose it is time someone mentioned the joke about the  mathematician inviting a topologist to a coffee  &....@Anton

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think possibly you were "being creative" when you wrote...

> For example, if it's a rectangle with 4 sides, then things can only pass in/out from one its side while other sides are blocked.

Consider:

> Physicists often get stuck with boring names for their work, Carroll said, and in the case of quarks, they needed to distinguish their characteristics. So they got creative, he said. Gell-Mann and George Zweig gave them “flavors” to describe their spin and electric charge — up, down and strange. Later physicists added the flavor “charm” to the mix, and quarks were further designated by the colors blue, green and red, even though the particles have no visible colors.

[PBS.com](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/science/whats-in-a-name-in-physics-everything-and-nothing)

In other words, physicists (and sometimes mathematicians) often use "colorful", "visual",  and "flavorful" language to describe aspects of functions.

Possibly this belongs on Math.SE, but  I would like to suggest ...

***Dimensional/ shape/color/side SORTER***

Based on the (mal)appropriation of [the name of the child's toy.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00000ITIV)

I think this goes one dimension more than what you asked, and is more discrete. i.e. It permits entry on one side only; moreover, it  selects by shape, and sometimes by color.

Optimum performance of entrance in such a [container](http://iconicmath.com/algebra/containers/) requires an outside intelligence such as a child, and can be measured statistically.  Exit is determined by random chance of a chaotic shaking...statistically a zero.

[image]

Comment: BTW...ask yourself: "Why are manhole covers always round?"

Comment: They aren't, some are rectangular, some are square, some are higher order polygons like octagons.

Comment: Downvoting this creative suggestionis unkind and does not encourage discussion or thought.

Comment: @BoldBen my bad...I should have said typically, not "always"... That said, I guess you never applied to Microsoft for a job..."The question of why manhole covers are typically round (in some countries) was made famous by [Microsoft when they began asking it as a job-interview question. "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhole_cover)

Answer (score 0):

In thermodynamics / statistical mechanics this could be called a blackbody box - see e.g. https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/purcells-black-body-box

See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/491434/164656

Or a pinhole camera?